# In what order MySQL permissions are applied on database?

Tags: mysql, permissions

I want to understand the priority of executing MySQL grants privileges.

**For e.g.:**

I want to grant two different types of privileges on a single db `Demo`.

**1.**`GRANT SELECT ON Demo.table1 TO abc@123;`

**2.**`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON Demo.* TO abc@123;`

As per my assumption, `no 2` grant will overwrite the limitations of `no 1` grant, therefore, ends up giving access to all tables including `table1` to `abc` user.

And if I want to give `SELECT` privilege for `table1` then I should change the order of executing permissions so that they don't get overwritten by `*`.

I'm not sure if this is how MySQL manages such permissions. 
Anyone with a different opinion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a matter of opinion; the manual clearly describes the logic of authorization checking, and it has nothing to do with the order in which you may or may not execute `GRANT`s.

Comment: No order. Assume all privileges checked in random order until ALLOW found or all grants checked. If not found - no access. It's because no DENY privilege.

Comment: @Akina - But the algorithm _could be_ that it sees #1 and decides that your only permission is for SELECT on table1, then stops.

Comment: A side note:  `REVOKE` removes an identical `GRANT`, but otherwise does nothing.  (This is elaborating on Akina's comment about `DENY`.)

Comment: @RickJames *t sees #1 and decides that your only permission is for SELECT on table1, then stops* When server looks for SELECT permission, it is true. But when it looks for, for example, UPDATE permission, it's false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MySQL 5.7 Documentation under [`Privileges Provided by MySQL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html)

> The privileges granted to a MySQL account determine which operations
>   the account can perform. MySQL privileges differ in the contexts in
>   which they apply and at different levels of operation:
>
> - Administrative privileges enable users to manage operation of the
>     MySQL server. These privileges are global because they are not
>     specific to a particular database.
> - Database privileges apply to a database and to all objects within it.
>     These privileges can be granted for specific databases, or globally so
>     that they apply to all databases.
> - Privileges for database objects such as tables, indexes, views, and
>     stored routines can be granted for specific objects within a database,
>     for all objects of a given type within a database (for example, all
>     tables in a database), or globally for all objects of a given type in
>     all databases.

From this, the order is:

- Global Privileges
- Database Privileges
- Table Privileges

The tables that drive the order are:

- `mysql.user`
- `mysql.db`
- `mysql.tables_priv`
- `mysql.columns_priv`

With regard to an identical username @ host, please note what pages 486,487 state about mysql's authentication algorithm from [**MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328127)

[image]

> There are two stages of client access control:
>
> In the first stage, a client attempts to connect and the server either
>   accepts or rejects the connection. For the attempt to succeed, some
>   entry in the user table must match the host from which the client
>   connects, the username, and the password.
>
> In the second stage (which occurs only if a client has already
>   connected sucessfully), the server checks every query it receives from
>   the client to see whether the client has sufficient privileges to
>   execute it.
>
> The server matches a client against entries in the grant tables based
>   on the host from which the client connects and the user the client
>   provides. However, it's possible for more than one record to match:
>
> Host values in grant tables may be specified as patterns contains
>   wildcard values. If a grant table contains entries from
>   `myhost.example.com`, `%.example.com`, `%.com`, and `%`, all of them
>   match a client who connects from `myhost.example.com`.
>
> Patterns are not allowed for the User values in grant table entries,
>   but a username may be given as an empty string to specify an anonymous
>   user. The empty string matches any username and thus effectively acts
>   as a wildcard.
>
> When the Host and the User values in more than one user table record
>   match a client, the server must decide which one to use. It does this
>   by sorting records with the most specific Host and User column values
>   first, and choosing the matching record that occurs first in the
>   sorted list, Sorting take place as follows:
>
> In the Host Column, literal values such as `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`,
>   and `myhost.example.com` sort ahead of values such as `%.example.com`
>   that have pattern characters in them. Pattern values are sorted
>   according to how specific they are. For example, `%.example.com` is
>   more specific than `%.com`, which is more specific than `%`.
>
> In the User column, non-blank usernames sort ahead of blank usernames.
>   That is, non-anonymous users sort ahead of anonymous users.
>
> The server performs this sorting when it starts. It reads the grant
>   tables into memory, sorts them, and uses the  in-memory copies for
>   access control.

When you look at these two perspectives, mysqld should always go top down when evaluating grants. Keep in mind that

- `GRANT SELECT ON Demo.table1 TO abc@123;` is stored in `mysql.tables_priv`
- `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON Demo.* TO abc@123;` is stored in `mysql.db`
- For more information, please see my older post [Unable to remove permission for mysql.user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107239/unable-to-remove-permission-for-mysql-user/107241#107241)

## AND THE OSCAR GOES TO ...

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON Demo.* TO abc@123;
```

Comment: Has it been a decade since End-of-life for 5.0??  (OK, most of the contents is still valid.)