# User privileges error on server maria db Create trigger Drop trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger, mariadb

User privileges error on server maria db

- `User` : user1
- `DB` : db1

Error

> 15:00:46 DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS audit_trigger Error Code:
>   1419. You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe
>   log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
>   0.266 sec

Script

```
DELIMITER $$  
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS audit_trigger$$ 
CREATE TRIGGER `audit_trigger` BEFORE UPDATE ON `table` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.dateModify <> NEW.dateModify THEN 
        INSERT INTO  table SELECT * FROM thistable where id = NEW.id ;  
    END IF ; 
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Is it possible to give super privileges for user1 to only db1 
i dont want this user to have access to other tables on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, one may set the mysterious parameter ‘log_bin_trust_function_creators’ to 1, that prevents the database from complaining against simple and inoffensive triggers. Though, setting this parameter requires

1. Open the “Parameter Groups” tab.
2. Create a new Parameter Group. On the dialog, select the MySQL family compatible to your MySQL database version, give it a name and confirm.
3. Select the just created Parameter Group and issue “Edit Parameters”.
4. Look for the parameter ‘log_bin_trust_function_creators’ and set its value to ‘1’.
5. Save the changes.
6. Open the “Instances” tab. Expand your MySQL instance and issue the “Instance Action” named “Modify”.
7. Select the just created Parameter Group and enable “Apply Immediately”.
8. Click on “Continue” and confirm the changes.
9. Again, open the “Instances” tab. Expand your MySQL instance and issue the “Instance Action” named “Modify”.
10. Dont forget: Open the “Instances” tab. Expand your MySQL instance and issue the “Instance Action” named “Reboot”.

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, I wrote about this back on `Jun 20, 2014`. If you look in my post [MySQL user without SUPER privilege](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68625/mysql-user-without-super-privilege/68632#68632), I clearly explain how running command like

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db1.table TO 'user1'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db1.* TO 'user1'@'%';
```

never gives away SUPER privilege

If you run this query

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND column_name='super_priv';
```

it only comes back with `user`.

```
+------------+
| table_name |
+------------+
| user       |
+------------+
```

Here is something interesting

- In MySQL 5.6, running [`DROP TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-trigger.html) requires the [`TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_trigger) privilege. Same is true for [MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-trigger.html), [MySQL 5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/drop-trigger.html), and [MySQL 5.1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/drop-trigger.html)
- In MySQL 5.0, running [`DROP TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-trigger.html) requires the [`SUPER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) privilege

Running this query

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND column_name='trigger_priv';
```

comes back with

```
+------------+
| table_name |
+------------+
| db         |
| user       |
+------------+
```

This shows you that globally and at the database level you can grant the `TRIGGER` privilege, provided the user can access the specified schema. You cannot give away the `TRIGGER` privilege to a user just for a single table.

Thus, if a user has full access to database db1 and you want that user to drop triggers in another database (such as db2), then simply run

```
GRANT TRIGGER ON db2.* TO user1@'%';
```

Be very careful how you assign individual grants like this

In your particular case, [`DROP TRIGGER` requires `TRIGGER` privilege in MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/drop-trigger/)

Answer (score 1):

According comment on  this page, https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/drop-trigger/:
It appears that there is a bug in MySQL which makes TRIGGER privilege not enough to create/drop triggers. Unfortunately it's also present in MariaDB 10.1.11

See: - stack-overflow comment - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627383/cant-create-mysql-trigger-with-trigger-privilege-on-5-1-32 - MySQL bug ticket - http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39489

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the table name in the `GRANT` statement like this:

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db1.table TO 'user1'@'%';
```

Or for all tables of <kbd>db1</kbd> like this:

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db1.* TO 'user1'@'%';
```